# Bit fiddling: Negate an int, only if it's negative

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I'm working through a codebase that uses the following encoding to indicate sampling with replacement: We maintain an array of ints as indicators of position *and* presence in the sample, where positive ints indicate a position in another array and negative ints indicate that we should not use the data point in this iteration.

Example:

```
data_points: [...] // Objects vector of length 5 == position.size()
std::vector<int> position: [3, 4, -3, 1, -2]
```

would mean that the first element in `data_points` should go to bucket 3, the second to bucket 4, and the fourth to bucket 1.
The negative values indicate that for this iteration we won't be using those data points, namely the 3rd and 5th data points are marked as excluded because their values in position are negative and have been set with `position[i] = ~position[i]`.

The trick is that we might perform this multiple times, but the positions of the data points in the index *should not change*. So in the next iteration, if we want to exclude data point 1, and include data point 5 we could do something like:

```
position[0] = ~position[0] // Bit-wise complement flips the sign on ints and subtracts 1
position[4] = ~position[4]
```

This will change the position vector into

```
    std::vector<int> position: [-4, 4, -3, 1, 1]
```

Now on to the question: At the end of each round I want to reset all signs to positive, i.e. position should become [3, 4, 3, 1, 2].

Is there a bit-fiddling trick that will allow me to do this without having an if condition for the sign of the value?

Also, because I'm new to to bit fiddling like this, why/how does taking the bit complement of a signed, positive int give us its mathematical complement? (i.e. the same value with the sign flipped)

Edit: The above is wrong, the complement of a (int) will give -(a + 1) and depends on the representation of ints as noted in the answers. So the original question of simply taking the positive value of an existing one does not apply, **we actually need to perform a bitwise complement to get the original value**.

Example:

```
position[0] = 1
position[0] = ~position[0] // Now position[0] is -2
//  So if we did
position[0] = std::abs(position[0]) // This is wrong, position[0] is now 2!
// If we want to reset it to 1, we need to do another complement
position[0] = ~position[0] // Now position[0] is again 1
```

Comment: any particular reason why you want to work on the level of bits, when you could use `position[0] = -position[0]` instead of `position[0] = ~position[0]` ?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you are using negative values in a somewhat convoluted way.  Personally, I would represent this with a vector of bools, `should_use_bucket`.  Then you can just clear the bools at the end of each round of processing.

Comment: is it about performance and you want to avoid branches ?

Comment: I would go for `std::abs`.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I also don't like using the position vector like this, but it's a large codebase I'm contributing to and I'm trying to keep changes to a minimum.

Comment: btw does it really matter that the negative will have the wrong absolute value? You just need `~~position[0] == position[0]` such that you can restore the correct positive value

Comment: @user463035818 no it doesn't the complement is used only with the purpose of getting a negative number from a positive one, then restoring the original positive number with another complement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the extended question: Again, first write the obvious and intuitive code and then check that your compiler does the right thing: [Look ma, no branches!](https://godbolt.org/z/1mQG52)

If you let it have its fun with auto-vectorization then you probably won't understand (or be good at judging) the assembly, so you have to profile anyway. Concrete example:
https://godbolt.org/z/oaaOwJ. **clang** likes to also unroll the auto-vectorized loop while **gcc** is more conservative. In any case, it's still branch-free.

Chances are that your compiler understands the nitty-gritty details of instruction scheduling on your target platform better than you. If you don't obscure your intent with bit-magic, it'll do a good job by itself. If it's still a hot spot in your code, you can then go and see if you can hand-craft a better version (but that will probably have to be in assembly).

Comment: Thanks, I need to get used to reading compiler output for simple things like this. Chances are it will do the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend not attempting bit fiddling. Partly because you're dealing with signed numbers, and you would throw away portability if you fiddle. Partly because bit fiddling is not as readable as reusable functions.

A simple solution:

```
std::for_each(position.begin(), position.end(), [](int v) {
    return std::abs(v);
});
```

---

> why/how does taking the bit complement of a signed, positive int give us its mathematical complement? (i.e. the same value with the sign flipped)

It doesn't. Not in general anyway. It does so only on systems that use 1's complement representation for negative numbers, and the reason for that is simply because that's how the representation is specified. A negative number is represented by binary complement of the positive value.

Most commonly used representation these days is 2's complement which doesn't work that way.

Comment: Will 2's complement give the result: complement of a (int) will give -(a + 1)?

Comment: @Bar You can use `-a`, which is portable to all sign representations. `(~a) + 1` would be correct for 2's complement, but I doubt there is never a reason to use it in stead of `-a`.

Comment: Agreed, not sure why the original author used the bitwise not here when they could be using negative. Probably to handle 0 as well, as `-0 == 0`, but `~0 != 0`.

Comment: @Bar ah, I think I'm starting to understand. If the requirement is to change any number greater *or equal* to zero to some (any) negative value, and revert using the same operation, the bitwise complement is quite convenient for that, except for the caveat that it relies on 2's complement. In 1's complement and in sign+magnitude representations 0 would be inverted to -0, which is technically negative, but not necessarily what was required.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the first go-to source for bit twiddling hacks: [The eponymous site](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs)

> ```
> int v;           // we want to find the absolute value of v
> unsigned int r;  // the result goes here 
> int const mask = v >> sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1;
>
> r = (v + mask) ^ mask;
> ```

However, I would question the assumption that `position[i] = std::abs(position[i])` has worse performance. You should definitely have profiling results that demonstrate the bit hack being superior before you check in that kind of code.

Feel free to play around with a quick benchmark (with disassembly) of both - I don't think there is a difference in speed:

[gcc 8.2](http://quick-bench.com/h93wco-JunS4byod_TZ9-MlD44A)

[clang 6.0](http://quick-bench.com/j2npZpJw62MqpKa_7rYb1hcHMqE)

Also take a look at the assembly that is actually generated:

https://godbolt.org/z/Ghcw_c

Evidently, **clang** sees your bithack and is not impressed - it generates a conditional move in all cases (which is branch-free). **gcc** does as you tell it, but has two more implementations of `abs` in store, some making use of register semantics of the target architecture.

And if you get into (auto-)vectorization, things get [even more muddy](https://godbolt.org/z/Swkyop). You'll have to profile regardless.

---

Conclusion: Just write `std::abs` - your compiler will do all the bit-twiddling for you.

Comment: Good point, a vectorized application of abs will probably have "good enough" performance. I don't think this lies in the hottest path of the program so I'd lean towards readable code.

Comment: Seems like I had a mistake in the original question: If we _do_ flip the value with a complement, then taking the abs _will not work_ as the absolute value will have changed! Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

Use functions to signify intent. Allow the compiler's optimiser to do a better job than you ever will.

```
#include <cmath>

void include_index(int& val)
{
    val = std::abs(val);
}

void exclude_index(int& val)
{
    val = -std::abs(val);
}

bool is_included(int const& val)
{
    return val > 0;
}
```

Sample output from godbolt's gcc8 x86_64 compiler (note that it's all bit-twiddling and there are no conditional jumps - the bane of high performance computing):

```
include_index(int&):
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
  sar eax, 31
  xor DWORD PTR [rdi], eax
  sub DWORD PTR [rdi], eax
  ret
exclude_index(int&):
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
  mov edx, DWORD PTR [rdi]
  sar eax, 31
  xor edx, eax
  sub eax, edx
  mov DWORD PTR [rdi], eax
  ret
is_included(int const&):
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
  test eax, eax
  setg al
  ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ni6DOk

Answer (score 1):

> Also, because I'm new to to bit fiddling like this, why/how does taking the bit complement of a signed, positive int give us its mathematical complement? (i.e. the same value with the sign flipped)

This question deserves an answer all by itself since everyone will tell you that this is how you do it, but nobody ever tells you why.

Notice that `1 - 0 = 1` and `1 - 1 = 0`. What this means is that if we do `1 - b`, where `b` is a single bit, the result is the opposite of `b`, or `not b` (`~b`). Also notice how this subtraction will never produce a borrow, this is very important, since `b` can only be at most `1`.

Also notice that subtracting a number with `n` bits simply means performing `n` 1-bit subtractions, while taking care of borrows. But our special case will never procude a borrow.

Basically we have created a mathematical definiton for the bitwise not operation. To flip a bit `b`, do `1 - b`. If we wanna flip an `n` bit number, do this for every bit. But doing `n` subtractions in sequence is the same as subtracting two `n` bit numbers. So if we wanna calculate the bitwise not of an 8-bit number, `a`, we simply do `11111111 - a`, and the same for any `n` bit number. Once again this works because subtracting a bit from `1` will never produce a borrow.

But what is the sequence of `n` "`1`" bits? It's the value `2^n - 1`. So taking the bitwise not of a number, `a`, is the same as calculating `2^n - 1 - a`.

Now, numbers inside a computer are stored as numbers modulo `2^n`. This is because we only have a limited number of bits available. You may know that if you work with 8 bits and you do `255 + 1` you'll get `0`. This is because an 8-bit number is a number modulo `2^8 = 256`, and `255 + 1 = 256`. `256` is obviously equal to `0` modulo `256`.

But why not do the same backwards? By this logic, `0 - 1 = 255`, right? This is indeed correct. Mathematically, `-1` and `255` are "congruent" modulo `256`. Congruent essentially means equal to, but it's used to differentiate between regular equality and equality in modular arithmetic.

Notice in fact how `0` is also congruent to `256` modulo `256`. So `0 - 1 = 256 - 1 = 255`. `256` is our modulus, `2^8`. But if bitwise not is defined as `2^n - 1 - a`, then we have `~a = 2^8 - 1 - a`. You'll notice how we have that `- 1` in the middle. We can remove that by adding `1`.

So we now have `~a + 1 = 2^n - 1 - a + 1 = 2^n - a`. But `2^n - a` is the negative `a` modulo `n`. And so here we have our negative number. This is called two's complement, and it's used in pretty much every modern processor, because it's the mathematical definition of a negative number in modular arithmetic modulo `2^n`, and because numbers inside a processor work as if they were in modulo `2^n` the math just works out by itself. You can add and subtract without doing any extra steps. Multiplication and division do require "sign extension", but that's just a quirk of how those operations are defined, the meaning of the number doesn't change when extending the sign.

Of course with this method you lose a bit, because you now have half of the numbers being positive and the other half negative, but you can't just magically add a bit to your processor, so the new range of value you can represent is from `-2^(n-1)` to `2^(n-1) - 1` inclusive.

Alternatively, you can keep the number as it is and not add `1` at the end. This is known as the one's complement. Of course, this is not quite the same as the mathematical negative, so adding, subtracting, multiplying and dividing don't just work out of the box, you need extra steps to adjust the result. This is why two's complement is the de facto standard for signed arithmetic. There's also the problem that, in one's complement, both `0` and `2^n - 1` represent the same quantity, zero, while in two's complement, negative `0` is still correctly `0` (because `~0 + 1 = 2^n - 1 + 1 = 2^n = 0`). I think one's complement is used in the Internet Protocol as a checksum, but other than that it has very limited purpose.

But be aware, "de facto" standard means that this is just what everyone does, but there is no rule that says that it MUST be done this way, so always make sure to check the documentation of you target architecture to make sure you're doing the right thing. Even though let's be honest, chances of finding a useful one's complement processor out there nowadays are pretty much null unless you're working on some extremely specific architecture, but still, better be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

"Is there a bit-fiddling trick that will allow me to do this without having an if condition for the sign of the value?"

Do you need to keep the numeric value of the number being changed from a negative value?

If not, you can use `std::max` to set the negative values to zero

```
iValue = std::max(iValue, 0); // returns zero if iValue is less than zero
```

If you need to keep the numeric value, but just change from negative to positive, then

```
iValue = std::abs(iValue); // always returns a positive value of iValue
```